# Merging or dissolving smaller features completely within in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I've got a shapefile dataset shown below.

I want to merge feature classes completely within larger ones, for example merge 325 with 314, and keep the row data of the larger feature (314).

[image]

I've tried a number of different tools, such as Dissolve and merge but these have created one large polygon as all the feature classes are overlapping.

Comment: Can you simply remove the 'holes' in the larger polygon(s), and then delete the smaller polygon(s)?  You can detect which polygons have holes by examining their geometries' 'rings' count.  You could then detect the smaller (inside) polygons by some creative use of the 'Union' tool.

Comment: How do you examine the ring count?

Comment: Ok I've mange to remove the 'holes' using a Select by Attributes to only include polygons of a certain area. 
The next step is to 'fill in the holes' - There are around 400 of them, is there an automated way of doing this besides deleting vertices?

Comment: Perhaps eliminate might help https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate.htm if you have an advanced license level.

Comment: You can remove holes by manually modifying the geometry.  You will need to use Python scripting to do this.  Either using stand-alone Python script, or creating a script tool with a nice GUI.

Comment: Don't you mean "features" instead of "feature classes"?  Or, is every polygon/feature in its own feature class?

Comment: Export smalls to dataset 'small', remove all fields. Delete smalls from parent. Spatial join one-2-one 'small' to parent (share line segment with). Append small to parent and dissolve. Note 451 might not go to 315. To set a priorities (longest boundary?) and use one-2-many.